# Python : How can I get HTTP POST/GET request header

Tags: python, http, header, request

I dont really know how to formulate my question but what I want to do goes like this :

I want to print or get all the http transaction, like when I press F12 in Chrome or FF and go to 
network I can see them.

I was trying to do it with urllib2 and requests and I didnt get what I want ..

Comment: You need to give us an example of what didn't work. If you use urlopen, the headers are right on the response object.

Answer (score 0):

The [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/) module is very powerful has ways to access response and request headers

```
In [16]: import requests

In [17]: r = requests.get("http://www.stackoverflow.com")

In [18]: r.headers
Out[18]: CaseInsensitiveDict({'content-length': '36531', 'content-encoding': 'gzip', 'set-cookie': 'prov=62ff4d3c-2d5f-413c-92f6-ad7d116088a9; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly', 'expires': 'Mon, 29 Sep 2014 16:29:48 GMT', 'vary': '*', 'last-modified': 'Mon, 29 Sep 2014 16:28:48 GMT', 'cache-control': 'public, no-cache="Set-Cookie", max-age=16', 'date': 'Mon, 29 Sep 2014 16:29:32 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'})

In [19]: r.request.headers
Out[19]: CaseInsensitiveDict({'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, compress', 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.5 Darwin/13.3.0'})
```

Comment: maybe I didnt get something right in the http but atm when I press F12 I can see a lot of GET and POST but when I do it in my code im getting only 1 .. how can I see what I see in the browser

Comment: @FordCrees Ah i didn't get that from the question. There are multiple http requests in the browser because it parses the HTML and loads image links, css, js etc. You'll need to do that yourself from the HTML from the initial link or maybe use a tool like selenium which you can drive a browser with code and capture the requests and headers